# WPF TextBlock MultiBinding

Tags: wpf, textblock, multibinding

I want to bind TextBlock's Text property to some elements' and some model's properties. Something like this:

```
<TextBlock>
    <TextBlock.Text>
        <MultiBinding>
            <Binding ElementName="myElement1" Mode="OneWay" Path="Text" />
            <Binding ElementName="myElement2" Mode="OneWay" Path="Text" />
            <Binding Mode="OneWay" Path="Property1" />
            <Binding Mode="OneWay" Path="Property2" />
        </MultiBinding>
    </TextBlock.Text>
</TextBlock>
```

The TextBlock has a text value, combination of myElement1, myElement2 and Property1, Property2. There is not a problem. The text value is generated successfully.

Here is my question:

Can I bind whole (combined) text value of the TextBlock to another model's property, i.e. Property3, without code?

Comment: I don't think you should program yourself into this situation if your using MVVM. The View Model should be exposing and binding to these item's individually and not rely on the View to provide it concatenated data. The View should be using MultiBinding to "Present" the data in various formats but that's not the same to putting data together and giving it back to the View-Model. The separation of responsibility is lost in such an implementation where the View is no longer just a Presenter of data.

Comment: Yes agree totally with Viv - this is not something you want your view to be doing - the model should expose concatenated data as a property if thats required (not get it in a round about way from the view).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not without some really bad hacking which would require writing some code to set up attached properties and other bindings anyway. The issue is that any binding has 2 ends: target and source. Since the target (where the binding is set) must be a DependencyProperty that means that your model must be on the source end of the binding you're trying to do. This isn't a problem as far as setting a value since TwoWay and OneWayToSource bindings do this just fine.

You have a bigger problem though in that the original place where the value is coming from (TextBlock.Text) already is assigned a binding and so can't be the target for your model binding. You might next want to try using another UIElement property as an intermediary to take the Text value and push it to the model. To do that you again need the model to be the source and the other UIElement property to be the target. But that same property also needs to be the target of a binding to the original Text property that you're trying to extract, so again you're stuck.

Bottom line is that you're much better off handling this in your Model and ViewModel layers rather than trying to force the stuff you have set up in XAML to be driving everything.

Comment: Thank you for all. I thought the same thing but I asked because "may be" there is an approach. I solved this case by assigning the field yo the TextBlock's text property just before http put / http post request.